# Android UI control like tag control

Tags: android, user-interface, tags, sms, android-controls

I want to know how to get a control that contains list of strings arranged as in an image bellow.

[image]

you can see the strings strings added in random way based on its width

I tried to use normal textview with inside a linear or relative layout with but it didnt work.
Can you pleae tell me the best practice to have a control that I pass to it a list of strings and it shows them like the image bellow ?

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: I want to display a list of strings similar to the screenshots I added

Comment: wait for help i am developing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a flow layout and toggle buttons inside it.
A good flow layout is available [here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout).
And the toggle buttons will need a Selector drawable to give it the proper checked/unchecked appearance.

Here is a selector example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rect_tag_checked" android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rect_tag_normal" android:state_checked="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rect_tag_normal"></item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Google [Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) can be used to displays tags. For your use-case *Input chips* will do the job. Read about it [here](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips). The tags/chips are completely customize-able.

The library is available for both Android and iOS so you can provide a consistent user interface for your users on both the platforms.